# Arrow Function doesn't trigger

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have the following code/snippet;

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  loginComponent = <button onClick={this.signUp}>Sign Up</button>;
  
  signUp = () => {
    alert("test");
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {this.loginComponent}
      </div>    
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
#root {
width: 50%;
height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

When signUp uses Arrow Syntax, the function doesn't execute. When I use regular syntax;

```
signUp() {
   alert("test);
}
```

It executes fine. Any idea as to what my problem is, here?

Comment: What are the contexts of these functions and `display` assignment. Is this inside a React class component? Some context would possibly help

Comment: Arrow functions do not have this. If 'this' is accessed, it is taken from the outside, where the arrow function is defined. Detailed explanation here https://javascript.info/arrow-functions

Comment: The function should be **called** either way, despite the differences in `this` noted above. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: You haven't shown any declarations for `display` or (in the first code block) `renderSignUpForm`. They **are** declared, right? Because if not, that code is falling prey to what I all [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), which could be a factor...

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca et. al. - there's no reason to believe this question is related to the `this` difference.

Comment: @ Kwxhvor - If you update your question with an [MCVE](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/), I can reopen it if the problem isn't `this` (which I doubt it is). (Or point you at a more appropriate dupetarget.)

Comment: Will do. Give me a second.

Comment: Updated as Requested @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're defining your properties in the wrong order. When you define `loginComponent`, the value of `this.signUp` is `undefined`.

Reverse the order so `signUp` is initialized first:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  signUp = () => {
    alert("test");
  };

  loginComponent = <button onClick={this.signUp}>Sign Up</button>;
  
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {this.loginComponent}
      </div>    
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
#root {
width: 50%;
height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

*(Also note the `;` at the end of the `signUp` assignment. ASI will add it for you, but it should be there if you aren't intentionally relying on ASI.)*

Remember that with [class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), public property definitions are handled *in order* during instance creation, *roughly* as though you had this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.signUp = () => {
      alert("test");
    };

    this.loginComponent = <button onClick={this.signUp}>Sign Up</button>;
  }

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

It worked with the method definition because methods are defined when the prototype is created (when the `class` declaration is processed), which is before instance initialization.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. Why was this only an issue with Arrow Syntax, and not with regular syntax?

Comment: @Kwxhvor - Hit refresh, I'd just added a note explaining that when you commented. :-)

Comment: @Kwxhvor the problem is not about the arrow syntax, if you store a "normal" function in a class property, it will do the same. It is about hoisting here.

Comment: Great, Thank you @T.J.Crowder